# How to Pull Field Data from InfoPath Form into SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, infopath, custom-list, infopath-data-connections

I am using SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath 2013. I have an existing SharePoint List that's populated by an existing InfoPath form. Currently, only a few fields that are from the form appear in the SharePoint list. Now, I want to add a few more columns from the form to appear in the SharePoint list. But do not know how to go about doing so. I was thinking to follow the steps below:

1. Open in Designer by using the SharePoint List URL in the Data Connection Wizard
2. Select the proper list
3. This is where I get stuck, because I do not want to modify the form I just want a few more fields from the form to appear as a column in the SharePoint list.

Can someone help me with the steps to have a few more form fields appear as columns in my SharePoint list?

Comment: columns are extracted in the list but in case of repeating tables where multiple entries in the same field are made and questions mentioned in the form not getting extracted as a report. That is getting saved as xml file with no questions

Answer (score 3):

You will need to promote those columns by re-publishing the form.  As you step through the wizard for publishing your infopath form a dialog appears where you can choose which columns you want to appear as promoted columns on the SharePoint list.

You can see the steps here in this blog post: http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx

If the link goes away this is the dialog below taken from that post.

[image: Promoted columns]